How would one build a working Linux volume for a 32-bit PowerPC headless platform using a non-PPC host?
Is there a tool similar to debootstrap for a recent Linux distribution that supports PPC so I could build a working system or have an automated process to cross-compile a base install?

Since you're tagging this embedded, I'll go with the embedded answer:
By cross-building a Linux image. That's what projects like buildroot and openembedded are for!
Note that if you need a debian image for something you know boots debian, http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/ports/snapshots/2024-02-25/ seems to still be supported, and you could try to build an image using Qemu as emulator.
However, I feel the openembedded-style approach is probably closer to what you want; you get a board support package (which is a definition of what the hardware is, including hardware that can't be automatically detected at boot), which often someone supplied (ideally a vendor), or you create one.
Then, you combine layers (say, a linux kernel, a bootloader, a shell, a webserver layer) and individual recipes so that your openembedded tooling generates a cross-development SDK for you, compiles the software packages you want for you, and builds a bootable image that you can flash to whatever your embedded platform boots from :)
The reality is that a lot of 32 bit PowerPC devices were made before openembedded became popular, so there's a better chance you find similar things for the buildroot tooling, which I'm not too familiar with. It does the same: you define hardware, you define which software you want, you get a bootable image, tools to compile and debug and package software for the target.

I read somewhere Debian ceased support for 32-bit PPC in Jessie, but that doesn't seem to be the case, however, I've had some trouble with Debian PPC binaries relying on Altivec extensions (which are absent on this part). The board is from a storage appliance with an NXP CPU, so no getting any board info that can't be captured post-boot. Bootloader is also a bit inflexible, but I can work from that layer and up.

I think debian stopped the official support
